# Is there a way to self promote old questions if I still need an answer?

Tags: discussion, support, old-questions

There are some old questions I am still looking an answer for and I wanted to know if there are ways to "revive" them.

I know you could start a bounty for some of them, and this may indeed be worth it for some of the hardest ones. But some I just don't think are worthy of a bounty. They are questions I would like an answer to and have not found one to the date but I can live without.

Comment: [Meta SE Dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer)

Comment: Edit the question

Comment: Probably the most effective way would be to post a *new* question with some defined differences from the original. Of course this is ethically questionable since you know the question is at least a partial duplicate (you can mark your own questions as duplicates, but still seems dubious). I suspect this would be down voted as an answer because there is so much duplication on SO (I would probably down vote myself!), but I think the reality is new questions receive the most short term attention

Comment: What do you mean by *self promote*? Is this about your own unanswered questions or about questions posted by others. This make a difference because, if they are yours, you at least know for sure, if the problem still persists.

Comment: In my mind, either (i) you care about a question → bounty it; or (ii) you don't → leave it be, why spend time promoting it?

Comment: At your current reputation level (just below 1k, for those reading this some time from now) a bounty of 50 may feel like a big thing ... but really, in the grand scheme of things, it isn't. If one of your questions was really interesting, it's not out of the question to get *somebody else* to offer a bounty. (Unfortunately, I couldn't find any unanswered questions of yours where I would even be competent to judge whether they are interesting.)

Comment: @tripleee does that mean my questions are bad or that my questions are in a field that you are not familair with?

Comment: Your questions are on topics I am not familiar with.  That's what "I'm not competent" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using existing systems, I find the best way is to edit the question. But don't just make some meaningless edit to jump it to the top of the queue. If the question's been around a while, make another attempt yourself to research the answer; then include any new findings in the question. That way, you're improving the questions that are out there as well as (hopefully) making your question more visible to get an answer.

The only other way is to bounty it, or persuade someone else to bounty it for you

Answer (score 6):

## Yes, there are quite a few ways to promote these questions!

*...but, is it really worth it?*

The problem is that after all this time, the OP is unlikely still searching for a solution to his or her problem. So we are dedicating more resources to answer these older questions that may or may not be useful to someone, while utilizing less resources to those who just posted a new question who we *know* can still use an answer.

But, that's not me saying this is a bad idea - I just like to get the cons out of the way first.

---

#### Now, what can we do to promote these older questions?

For starters, we can have a *Question of the Day* that features one unanswered question for each tag. Since these unanswered questions are likely to be more difficult than the newer ones (likely the reason for these questions going unanswered), there could potentially be a rep bonus for those who answer it *(I am talking about an insignificant bonus, mind you. Somewhere in the ball part of 110% - so 11 rep per upvote rather than 10. This would last for that day only)*.

Another option is a system-generated bounty. A small bounty, such as 15 rep (which is the amount for an accepted answer) to maybe 50. This bounty would place these questions in the featured tab to draw more attention.

---

The question remains, however. Is this a worthy project? Will users see a significant benefit from these questions being answered? If the answer is yes, then we certainly need to implement additional exposure on these questions, and provide incentive to those who can answer them well.

Comment: How many questions remain unanswered each day? Could that *Question of the Day* encompass all that unanswered questions?

Comment: You appear to have read the question differently than I did. I read the question as the OP asking for how they can, *right now*, promote some older, currently existing, questions. You appear to have answered: "Does anyone have any ideas for new features which could promote older questions?"

Comment: Important point to consider: starting a bounty can backfire. Bountying random old questions has a very high probability of backfiring and causing those questions to be downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: @Makyen Indeed I did... But this has the indirect effect of solving OP's issue since there would be less unanswered questions to begin with.

Comment: @Justastudent Such negative response is usually because such questions are of poor quality, or off-topic. If the question is of high-quality and on-topic, it's rare for it to get such a negative response. Without knowing the questions the OP has in mind, we, obviously, can't know. Of course, if the OP was to link to such example questions, it's likely that they would get up-/down-votes as a result of the Meta Effect.

Comment: @alseether It's quite possible upon rotation that the "Question of the Day" can certainly encompass every question _eventually_. Keep in mind, this would be on a _per-tag_ basis. As I do not have the data to sufficiently answer your question, I can see that every unanswered question on SO could eventually benefit from this feature.

Comment: Taking @Makyen's comment even further, I read it like *how can I promote my* ***own*** *unanswered questions*. As I mentioned in my [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364287/is-there-a-way-to-self-promote-old-questions?cb=1#comment563357_364287) on the question this narrows it down because you know the issue still persists and there is someone (yourself) interested in finding a solution. This adds kind of a personal touch to it rather than being an effort to cleaning up the site by answering old questions nobody might care about anymore.

Comment: True, @altocumulus. It can be interpreted that way (without additional clarification from OP). If that's the intent, then that's the reason the bounty system exists. Everyone wants to find alternatives to issuing bounties because they cost rep --- but at the same time everyone wants their question to "be at the top". Bounties are the best way to "self-promote", and it's intended that way because of my second point.

Comment: There are currently [2,041,599 unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+closed%3An+answers%3A0). Please explain how it's remotely feasible to have this "Question of the Day" feature every question eventually. Note that you will need to take into account the rate at which that number is increasing. I'm not saying its a bad idea, just trying to point out the scale on which it has to operate, if you expect it to get to every question.

Comment: @Makyen So your suggestion is to just _leave it that way_? Out of that number, how many unique tags do we have? This is just a rough guess, but 2,000,000 unanswered questions out of my theoretical 5,000 tags is 400 days of questions. Those date back from the start of this site, so while yes, it could take over a year, once we catch up the unanswered questions then we will be in short supply.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs You also need to take into account the population of questions within the tags. Many low-volume tags have only a few questions in them. High volume tags have much larger numbers (e.g. [tag:javascript] is [202,772 unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+is%3Aq+closed%3An+answers%3A0)). Note that the above numbers of questions don't include the large number of questions which get deleted (after 30 days, or 1 year) when they haven't been answered and meet other criteria. Presumably you want to include those.

Comment: @Makyen Yes, we would include all eligible questions. Regardless of when the expected deletion is, if it's not deleted, then it's eligible to be featured. I'm not saying this is perfect by any means, but it's **much** better than the system which we currently have in place (which quite frankly, doesn't really exist). We can just let that number _continue to climb_ by doing nothing, or we can be proactive about it and get these questions answered, one day at a time.

Comment: I completely agree, @Makyen. My comment was directed at the "random question(s) of the day" idea. Given that many bad unanswered questions float around, the probability of selecting one of those is quite high. That will also kill the idea, because contributors will quickly learn that it's not worthwhile to look at the question(s) of the day anymore. Of course, the selection could be ... not random. But how?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think an answer is the appropriate place to propose such a complex feature loosely related to the question (this question is about being able to self promote questions, your answer is about randomly promoting questions). If you want it implemented, post a feature request and elaborate on why such a feature would be beneficial, and elaborate further on how it could be implemented.

Comment: This requires a cleanup step: of all unanswered questions (*2 million!? Good god*) there will be a fair number which are not worth keeping to begin with, so  those need to be pruned out first. Then you end up with probably a much smaller set of unanswered questions which could make the proposed question of the day work. I wish us all good luck doing that monumental task.

Comment: i'm resurecting this one with a 500 bounty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478531/call-f-code-from-c-sharp

Comment: A major flaw with this approach is what happens with questions where the OP has yet to accept an answer. From my understanding, the system will deem these questions as "unanswered". Unless there is a means for the community to mark an answer as the accepted answer that I am simply unaware about, a lot of questions that don't actually require answers will be picked up.

Comment: @Tyler I would say it would chose questions that do not have upvoted answers. Acceptance of an answer would count as upvoted. That way if a question has a low quality answer it would still qualify to be featured

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs That's a good idea... Mainly because the general community can control whether a question fits the criteria or not.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't attempt to resurrect a long dead question. More important is to realise why it remained unanswered.

- Was it unclear?
- Was it not specific enough?
- Was there insufficient information?

Given the passage of time, one would hope to have more information, and knowledge, to impart to the question. This then will make it sufficiently different (and improved) to be considered, and posted as, a new question.

---

Consider that a bounty, of itself, does not improve the quality of the question.

Comment: A common reason you did not include is "no one saw it that could/wanted to answer it". A bump and/or a bounty can fix for questions that don't have an inherent quality problem.